# React calculator, which uses userReducer hook for operation, not working. Numbers not displaying

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, calculator, react-props, use-reducer

I am making a calculator using the useReducer hook in React.
I have made the useReducer hook to carry out all the operations, and the digit /operation buttons, on the calculator keyboard, are replaced by components which call the reducer. I am assuming there is a mistake somewhere in the syntax, as on pressing the buttons, no digits or operation symbols are showing up in the calculator display. The button component is getting rendered.

````
The reducer Function --->

 import React , {useReducer ,useState}from "react";
import ButtonDigit from "./ButtonDigit";
import ButtonOperation from "./ButtonOperation";
import "./style.css"

export const ACTIONS = {
  ADD_DIGIT : 'add-digit',
  DELETE_DIGIT: 'delete-digit',
  CLEAR: 'clear',
  CHOOSE_OPERATION: 'choose-operation',
  EVALUATION: 'evaluation'
}

function reducer (state, action) { 
   switch(action.type){
    case ACTIONS.ADD_DIGIT: 
      return {...state, currentOperand: `${state.currentOperand || ""}${action.payload}`}  
    case ACTIONS.DELETE_DIGIT:
      return state
    case ACTIONS.CLEAR:
      return {currentOperand: 0}
    case ACTIONS.CHOOSE_OPERATION:
      return state
    case ACTIONS.EVALUATION:
      return state
    default:
      return state
   }
}
export default function App() {
  const [{prevOperand=null, currentOperand =0, operation=null}, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,{})
  // console.log("Rendered!")
  // dispatch({payload:})
  return (
    <div className="calculator-grid">
      <div className="output">
        <div className="prev-operand">{prevOperand} {operation}</div>
        <div className="current-operand">{currentOperand}</div>
      </div>
        <button className="span-two">AC</button>
        <button>DEL</button>
        <ButtonOperation operation={'/'} dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="1" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="2" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="3" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonOperation operation={'*'} dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="4" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="5" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="6" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonOperation operation={'+'} dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="7" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="8" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="9" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonOperation operation={'-'} dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonOperation operation={'.'} dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <ButtonDigit number="0" dispatch={dispatch}/>
        <button className="span-two">=</button>
        {/* <ButtonOperation className="span-two" operation={'='} dispatch={dispatch}/>      */}
    </div>
  );
}


The <ButtonDigit/> Component ----->

import React from 'react'
import ACTIONS from './App'

export default function ButtonDigit({number,dispatch}) {

  // console.log(number)
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type:ACTIONS.ADD_DIGIT , payload:number})}
       >{number}</button>
    </>
  
  )
}
</code>```

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/KS-E/Calculator_useReducer)

The reducer function: 

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdetz.jpg)

The buttons and the props being passed :

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb5oZ.jpg)

The button component:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx54t.jpg)



I seemingly have a good understanding of how the useReducer hook works, however, I am unable to see where the mistake is, in the basic commands that I have used. Can someone please check? I am assuming I have made a mistake in the syntax of the props while passing them (or) while calling the reducer function via dispatch.

IMPORTANT NOTE: The code above is incomplete since I am stuck in the very first step itself (display of the digits on the display panel). Please check the ACTIONS.ADD_DIGIT and the corresponding commands.
````

Comment: It'll be easier for others to answer your question if they can view and copy/paste your code from the question itself. You can write code blocks by enclosing the code in triple backticks: \`\`\`<code>\`\`\`

Answer (score 0):

**ACTIONS.CHOOSE_OPERATION** is doing nothing now. So when you press an operation, nothing happened. So I think you should update this case

Comment: But what about the ACTIONS.ADD_DIGIT ? I am, unfortunately, stuck in the very first step itself. Since I couldn't get through that I haven't proceeded further with the code.

Answer (score 0):

After checking, I found that the issue is with the import ACTIONS from './App' statement. It is likely a problem with a circular import, which is causing the value ACTIONS.ADD_DIGIT to be undefined when it is used in the button component. The solution is to move the ACTIONS enum to a different file.